# Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 has stopped working?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

Crashes on startup of VS2005 or any VS2005 project.

Not sure what has changed... other than our IT departement keeps doing updates... still no clue why?

---

[image]

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  8.0.50727.42
  Application Timestamp:    4333e699
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_b07c
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c000041d
  Exception Offset: 777e1221
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.49
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: b07c
  Additional Information 2: b07c9f334ed23629f31261200e2152db
  Additional Information 3: c5e2
  Additional Information 4: c5e2938eff61fd2d71b1da696b2907b3

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

---

[image]

---

Tried debugging and get this:(and just cycles back to the original error)

[image]

Comment: Tell us more about the circumstances - does this crash happen when starting VS2005, or does it only happen when opening a certain solution or project?

Comment: Crashes on startup of VS2005 or any VS2005 project

Comment: does running VS2005.exe with /SafeMode help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Meh, don't try too hard.  This is a good way to finally get everybody a VS update.  8 years is a lot of dog lives in software engineering.

Comment: In regular mode:  Tried running as Administrator... same error.

Comment: In safe-mode OS boot up, it works.  In the safemode cmd with switch... it gets the same error.